# Grunt auto reload not work with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

My app.js file code (Node JS)

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');


fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);
});
```

My Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    reload: {
        port: '8000',
        proxy: {
            host: 'localhost'
        }
    },
    watch:{
        files:['index.html'],
        tasks:['reload']
    }

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-reload');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['reload']);

};
```

When Node on command grunt giv error

Proxying [//localhost:80/]
reload server running at [//localhost:8000]
Fatal error: listen EADDRINUSE

and when Node is off Grund command

Running "reload" task
Proxying [//localhost:80/]
reload server running at [//localhost:8000]

Done, without errors.

but file is not reload.